# Average loss stuck on local minima (Self developed Perceptron in C#)

Tags: c#, machine-learning

I am trying to build a custom machine learning library in C# , I have researched fairly about the topic. My first example (XOR estimator) was a success, I was able to lower the average loss to almost cero. Then I tried to build a model to classify handwritten digits (using MNIST text database).The problem is ,no matter how I configure the model, I always get stuck on a certain average loss over the data set.Second problem, because the MNIST dataset is very large, the model takes a lot of time to compute, maybe I can use some advice on how to carry on the slowest parts of the algorithm (I am using stochastic gradient descent).I am going to show the main method that performs most of the work.

I have tried using MSE and CrossEntropy loss functions, also tanh , sigmoid , reLu and softPlus activation functions. The model I am trying to build is a 4 layer one. First layer, 784 input neurons ; Second , 16 neurons,sigmoid ; Third , 16 neurons , sigmoid and Output layer, 10 neurons (one hot encoded digits) with sigmoid. I am aware that the code below may not be a minimal reproducible example, but it represents the algorithm I am trying to figure. I have also uploaded the solution to GitHub, maybe somebody can give me a hand figuring the problem. This is the link https://github.com/juan-carvajal/MachineLearningFramework
Running the Main method of the app will first, execute the XOR classifier, that runs good. Then the MNIST classifier.

The model is best represented here:

```
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("mnist2.txt", ' ', 10, false);
            //This creates a model with batching=128 , learningRate=0.5 and 
            //CrossEntropy loss function
            var p = new Perceptron(128, 0.5, ErrorFunction.CrossEntropy())
            .Layer(784, ActivationFunction.Sigmoid())
            .Layer(16, ActivationFunction.Sigmoid())
            .Layer(16, ActivationFunction.Sigmoid())
            .Layer(10, ActivationFunction.Sigmoid());
            //1000 is the number of epochs
            p.Train2(dataSet, 1000);
```

Actual Algorithm (stochastic gradiente descent):

```
Console.WriteLine("Initial Loss:"+ CalculateMeanErrorOverDataSet(dataSet));
            for (int i = 0; i < epochs; i++)
            {   
                //Shuffle the data in every step
                dataSet.Shuffle();
                List<DataRow> batch = dataSet.NextBatch(this.Batching);
                //Gets random batch from the dataSet
                int count = 0;
                    foreach (DataRow example in batch)
                    {

                    count++;

                    double[] result = this.FeedForward(example.GetFeatures());
                        double[] labels = example.GetLabels();
                        if (result.Length != labels.Length)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Inconsistent array size, Incorrect implementation.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //What follows is the calculation of the gradient for this example, every example affects the current gradient, then all those changes are averaged an every parameter is updated.
                            double error = CalculateExampleLost(example);


                            for (int l = this.Layers.Count - 1; l > 0; l--)
                            {
                                if (l == this.Layers.Count - 1)
                                {
                                    for (int j = 0; j < this.Layers[l].CostDerivatives.Length; j++)
                                    {
                                    this.Layers[l].CostDerivatives[j] = ErrorFunction.GetDerivativeValue(labels[j], this.Layers[l].Activations[j]);

                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    for (int j = 0; j < this.Layers[l].CostDerivatives.Length; j++)
                                    {

                                        double acum = 0;
                                        for (int j2 = 0; j2 < Layers[l + 1].Size; j2++)
                                        {
                                            acum += Layers[l + 1].WeightMatrix[j2, j] * this.Layers[l+1].ActivationFunction.GetDerivativeValue(Layers[l + 1].WeightedSum[j2]) * Layers[l + 1].CostDerivatives[j2];
                                        }
                                        this.Layers[l].CostDerivatives[j] = acum;
                                    }
                                }

                                for (int j = 0; j < this.Layers[l].Activations.Length; j++)
                                {
                                    this.Layers[l].BiasVectorChangeRecord[j] += this.Layers[l].ActivationFunction.GetDerivativeValue(Layers[l].WeightedSum[j]) * Layers[l].CostDerivatives[j];
                                    for (int k = 0; k < Layers[l].WeightMatrix.GetLength(1); k++)
                                    {
                                        this.Layers[l].WeightMatrixChangeRecord[j, k] += Layers[l - 1].Activations[k]
                                            * this.Layers[l].ActivationFunction.GetDerivativeValue(Layers[l].WeightedSum[j])
                                            * Layers[l].CostDerivatives[j];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }



                    }
                    TakeGradientDescentStep(batch.Count);

                if ((i + 1) % (epochs / 10) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Epoch " + (i + 1) + ", Avg.Loss:" + CalculateMeanErrorOverDataSet(dataSet));
                }
            }
```

[image: Here is an example of the local minima]

This is an example of what the local minima looks like in the current model.
In my research I found out that similar models may archieve accuracy up to 90%. My model barely got 10%.

Comment: What are you using to try to climb out of the local minima?

Comment: @Strom Hi Strom, I was hoping that the random batching at each step would prevent the model from getting stuck in local minima, is there a more efective way to do it?

Comment: You need to add a jitter step: add or subtract a small random values to the weights in the hidden layers every couple(10 to 100) of epochs. This will increase your overall training time, but it will give the system a way to recover.

Comment: Gradiant descent will never increase the error, batching will only increase the error a little(Note the variation in your losses), you need to introduce error to allow it to move beyond the local minimum, enough of a variation to over come one of the local maximum surrounding it.